# Core data dataModel issue in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, ios7

I am new to coredata, using it for the first time in an [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) application project,
and have no idea how to add entities with relations. The scenario is this:

There is an Order(entity) -> has multiple Vendors(entity) ->every vendor has multiple Items(entity)

How to design this thing? Can anyone share a good tutorial, example for above mentioned thing?

Comment: So your question is "How can I google **core data tutorial**"?

Comment: Don't use SO user to google for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at Ray Wenderlich's tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

Your project (Order/Vendor/Item) is quite simple.
You need to create the three entities and draw a relation between them.
(Note: Every relation is two-way! One order has multiple vendors, each vendor has one (or zero if you like) orders.)
On one-to-may-relationships you can set the deletion mode to cascade on the "Order"-side (and to clear on the "Vendors"-side). This way, all Vendors get deleted if you delete an order.

There is a lot to say about core data, (but I should stop talking, just look at Wenderlich's great tutorial)